# View a man page in a specific section

Tags: man

I wanted to access man pages for command `chmod`.

Command `whatis chmod` gave this output:

`chmod (2)            - change permissions of a file
 chmod (1)            - change file mode bits`

But I was actually looking for `chmod(2)`.

When I type `man chmod`, man pages for `chmod(1)` appears.

Both `man chmod(2)` and `man 'chmod(2)'` commands show error.

I tried running `info coreutils 'chmod invocation'`, but output is some kind of documentation which doesn't look like a typical man page.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Type: `man 2 chmod`, or `man -a chmod` to get all the versions.

Note: `man -a chmod` may be useful on some systems, because there may be other man pages on the same function, which may give additional information. For instance, under Debian, if the manpages-posix-dev package is installed, there's also the chmod(3posix) man page, also accessible via `man 3 chmod`.